# About accessing file (names) in specific directory and changing it

Tags: bash

I'm writing code to exchange the upper and lower alphabet of file's name in certain directory.
If directory is unable to access, it shows err message.

---

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 0 ];then

    path=$(pwd)
    for a in "$path"/*
    do
         mv "$i" "`echo $i | tr '[:upper:][:lower:]' '[:lower:][:upper:]'`"
    done

else

    if [ ! -d "$1" ];then
        echo "Unable to access directory!"
    else
        for i in "$1"/*
        do
            mv "$i" "`echo $i | tr '[:upper:][:lower:]' '[:lower:][:upper:]'`"
        done
        fi
 fi
```

---

The problem is that, when I echo `$i`, it doesn't express ONLY filename, but filename with directory!
So, when I try to mv the file, not only file's name is changed but ALSO directory's name is changed so I can't mv the file. 
Like this:

```
mv: cannot move 'test3/Ipad.txt' to 'TEST3/iPAD.TXT': No such file or directory
mv: cannot move 'test3/iPhone' to 'TEST3/IpHONE': No such file or directory
mv: cannot move 'test3/macOS' to 'TEST3/MACos': No such file or directory
```

how can I change the file names in certain directory?

Any help would be appreciable and thanks in advance.

Comment: Please properly format your code so we can read it. Also see [mcve]

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Is it okay now?

Comment: `for a in` and then you do `mv $i` ...

Comment: Try  https://shellcheck.net to validate your script.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about this grammar-checking site. Thanks Jetchisel!

Comment: @Jetchisel

If you won't mind, I'd like to ask more about accessing file in directory. I googled and find a multiple way of doing it such as : (for entry in $searchdir/*) (for entry in ls $search_dir) (for i in *) I tried these and when I echoed, it showed directory&files. Can you tell me what is standard way to access files in certain directory?

Comment: If you want to loop for files in the current directory/forlder `for files in *; do echo "$files"; done`

Comment: The problem is you're also renaming the directory of the files.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a single loop for handling both cases.

```
#! /bin/sh -
case $# in
( 0 ) path=. ;;
( * ) path=$1
esac

for fpath in "$path"/*; do
  echo mv -- "$fpath" "${fpath%/*}/$(
    printf '%s\n' "${fpath##*/}" |
      tr '[a-zA-Z]' '[A-Za-z]')"
done
```

If the path given by user is not present or accessible, this'll error out without causing any harm. But if you insist on handling that yourself, add a check before loop, or, use nullglob with bash and the script will exit silently on such an occasion.

Also note that the possibility that files having neither upper nor lower case letters in their names may exist is ignored here. Nothing will happen to them but mv will complain that source and target are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to cd to the directory first, then work on filenames in the directory:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then

    path=$(pwd)
    cd "$path"
    for a in *
    do
        mv "$i" "`echo $i | tr '[:upper:][:lower:]' '[:lower:][:upper:]'`"
    done
    cd -
else

    if [ ! -d "$1" ]; then
        echo "Unable to access directory!"
    else
        cd "$1"
        for i in *
        do
            mv "$i" "`echo $i | tr '[:upper:][:lower:]' '[:lower:][:upper:]'`"
        done
        cd -
    fi
fi
```

Comment: pwd is the current directory, what is the point of cd'ing into it?

Comment: True; is to only to illustrate the "cd $dir ; ... ; cd -;" pattern.

Comment: @rtx13

If you won't mind, I'd like to ask more about accessing file in directory.
 I googled and find a multiple way of doing it such as :


(for entry in $searchdir/*)
(for entry in `ls $search_dir`)
(for i in *)


I tried these and when I echoed, it showed directory&files. Can you tell me what is standard way to access files in certain directory?

Comment: @Hyunseo this will find files (and only files) in the current directory, including "hidden" files that start with a period (.) that `ls *` will not show: `find . -type f -maxdepth 1`.